# MongoDB + Mongoose: $set only if given key does not exist or have falsy value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I need a help on a findOneAndUpdate({upsert: true}) query:

got this shchema:

```
    usersSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {type: String, unique: true, uniqueCaseInsensitive: true},    // username
        password: {type: String, minlength: 4},
        slug: {type: String, unique: true, uniqueCaseInsensitive: true},    // ok - Automatic on backend - based on name
        firstName: {type: String},
        middleName: {type: String},
        lastName: {type: String},
        email: {type: String, unique: true, uniqueCaseInsensitive: true},
        //country: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 3}
        socialIDs: {
            facebook: {
                id: {type: String, unique: true}
            },
            twitter: {},
            google: {}
        }
    }
```

when user is new, creating account using facebook (with passportjs), the data of firstName, lastName, email, etc are populated with facebook retrieved data. if the user has created his account via local strategy, those fields may be non-existent and, the first time he log in with facebook, they got populated (updating profile).

perfect.

lets say now, the user update manually his profile via online form, BEFORE log in with facebook his first time, and set up a e-mail address (different from the associated with his facebook account).

when he log in with his facebook, the email address will be overwritten with the one retrieved from his facebook account.

is there a way to set the findOneAndUpdate() method to only insert keys that are non-existent (or maybe values on given key default falsy value)?

maybe combining $set with $exists operators somehow (I have tried this, but could not figure out correct syntax)

the query I am using is the following:

```
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            $or: [
                {email: profile._json.email},
                {socialIDs: {facebook: {id: profile._json.id}}}
            ]
        },
        {
            $set: {
                firstName: profile._json.first_name,
                middleName: profile._json.middle_name,
                lastName: profile._json.last_name,
                avatar: profile._json.picture,
                gender: profile._json.gender,
                email: profile._json.email,
                socialIDs: {
                    facebook: {
                        id: profile._json.id,
                        profileLink: profile._json.link,
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {new: true, upsert: true},
        function(err, user){
            done(err, user)
        });
```

thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

there's no conditional `$set`, however, if the user has already created an account and he **has** to provide his email when he does, then logging in with Facebook shouldn't overwrite it, which means you can remove the email from the `$set` operator.

Once you have this, you are left with the use case where a user has not signed up yet (upsert), in that case, you can use `$setOnInsert` to only in that scenario set the email.

Comment: Actually, your answer solve the email problem, but my question is still valid for the user firstName, lastName, etc. If the user create account with just email and password, then update his profile via form, and then login with facebook, it will overwrite all those info (which may be undesired). Any thought? @arg20

Comment: True, well, it seems like you'll have to fetch the model first. I can't think of a way to do it without querying the db first. It's not the worst either, later on you may want to store data in your model that you'll need when users sign in. Whether their account is activated or login count, etc.